# Django Tailwind theme refresh - won't load

Tags: django, tailwind-css

I have successfully installed `[django tailwind][1]` on my project.

The problem is with the preview.

As the installation guide advised, i tried `'python manage.py tailwind start'`, but the usual port http://127.0.0.1/ says: ***This site can’t be reached.***

If I start with my usual command of `'python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080'`, I can see the site and the new css, but it does not reload the page with **reload-worker.js**

If I try to reload the browser with the button, it just goes into a spinning icon in the tab, never reloads and i have to restart the browser and also the server.
So i can't really see the css changes, which is very annoying.

What am i missing here?

Reload listener seems to be working:

```
HTTP GET /static/django-browser-reload/reload-listener.js 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:52032]
HTTP GET /static/css/dist/styles.css 200 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:52031]
HTTP GET /static/django-browser-reload/reload-worker.js 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:52031]
```

Answer (score 0):

Might a bit late, but you have to start tailwind AND the server.
I'm using two terminals for this, as one gets occupied by each running system (server and tailwind reloader).